# Exact same one-line SASS code works in one rails project, but not another

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

First of all this is my first time posting a question on StackOverflow. I'm a big fan. Anyway:

I was doing the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl when, after editing the custom.scss.css file, I suddenly got this error:

> SASS Syntax error
>
> Undefined variable: "$gray".
>     (in /home/shady/workspace/ruby/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:4)

This isn't a problem with $gray; it is the correct way to spell and capitalize the gray SASS variable (I checked, and it works in another rails project). I simplified the custom.scss.css file to pinpoint this error, so all it contains is this:

```
@import "bootstrap";
  h1 {
   color: $gray;
}
```

In my Sample App (the rails tutorial app), I still get this error, but when I use this exact same code in another rails project that I created (to practice the things I learned in the Rails Tutorial on my own, so it pretty much mimics the Sample App), with the exact same gemset and Gemfile, this works perfectly fine. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=SecondTry

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'

end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '>=4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>=3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '2.2.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

This was working perfectly fine the last time I edited custom.scss.css, and I haven't done anything substantial since then. I haven't (at least purposefully) edited any file that I think would cause this. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling bootstrap-sass, but it hasn't worked. I believe it's a problem with SASS, but as I'm a rails newbie I have no clue on how to fix it. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED IT HAHAHAHAAAAAAA

It was because, for some stupid reason, I added an assets folder in the /vendor directory (probably testing something else out), and it seems that rails checks this directory for any external stylesheets and if it finds that it exists it loads from there instead of the gem (?), which is why bootstrap wasn't even processed by the Rails asset pipeline. The assets folder was empty save for a stylesheets and js folder. Once I deleted the assets folder the application started working again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to defined your $grey var somewhere. In my rails projects i usually set a _colors.scss partial where i defined all my var and then i import them before bootsrap so i can override them if i need.

```
$grey:#EEEEEE;
```

I don't see any $grey var in the bootstrap var list (http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables).

Another idea, i don't know how you call your stylesheet in your layout. But maybe if you call application.scss only, there might be a missing  *= require where your $grey is defined.

Comment: It's there, I think you're just looking in the wrong place. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less Also I didn't define $gray for the second project I used it in and it worked just fine. And I call it custom.scss.css, no particular reason, it's just the way I was taught it by the tutorial.

Comment: Can you try another variable to check if others colors are working or if the _variable.scss might be causing troubles? Is the gem is at the same version in both projects?

Comment: I just start a rails app from scratch with your gem file and $gray is working. I can't reproduce the error. Can you share your code?

Comment: I actually fixed it, took me a few hours. Check my answer